# PHP Soap Server without Soap Client

Tags: php, web-services, authentication, zend-framework, soap

There are several weeks that I'm trying to create a soap server in php that at first serves a wsdl with authentication header on it and at second it accepts only authenticated users in every request. But I' ve only made it fully working only without authentication. Every search I 've made and every solution I 've found contains a SoapClient,Zend_Soap_Client,nu_soap_client (you name it) and either some kind of wrapper class around my class or only addition of username & password on the client. 
But at my solution only the server is in php and client are various programs written in java etc, **not** in php. Here is my code for (I use [zend](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-soap) here but the idea is the same on plain php) the wsdl generation and the server part:

```
use Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover as Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover;
use Zend\Soap\Server as Zend_Soap_Server;

 if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
    $autodiscover = new Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover();
    $autodiscover->setClass('MyClass');
    $autodiscover->setUri('http://Myclass/path/');
    $autodiscover->handle();
     exit;
 }

 $server = new Zend_Soap_Server(null, array(
     'uri' => 'http://Myclass/path/',
 ));

 $server->setClass('Myclass');
 $server->handle();
```

I also used [piotrooo](https://github.com/piotrooo/wsdl-creator)'s wsdl generator and plain php soap library  like this:

```
use WSDL\WSDLCreator;
// use WSDL\XML\Styles\DocumentLiteralWrapped;

 if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
     $wsdl = new WSDL\WSDLCreator('Myclass', 'http://Myclass/path/');
     $wsdl->setNamespace("http://Myclass/path/");
     $wsdl->renderWSDL();
     exit;
 }

 $server = new SoapServer(null, array(
     'uri' => 'http://Myclass/path/',
    //  'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
    //  'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
 ));
 $server->setClass('Myclass');
 $server->handle();
```

And my class:

```
class Myclass
{
public function __construct()
    {
      /*some db stuff with doctrine*/
    }
    /**
     * @param string $id
     * @return object
     */
    public function Id($id)
    {
       /*I'm using doctrine to fetch data from db and then return an object/or array*/
    }
}
```

At last this is the auto generated wsdl:

```
<definitions name="Myclass" targetNamespace="http://Myclass/path/"><types><xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://Myclass/path/"/></types><portType name="MyclassPort"><operation name="Id"><documentation>Id</documentation><input message="tns:IdIn"/><output message="tns:IdOut"/></operation></portType><binding name="MyclassBinding" type="tns:MyclassPort"><soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/><operation name="Id"><soap:operation soapAction="http://Myclass/path/#Id"/><input><soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://Myclass/path/"/></input><output><soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://Myclass/path/"/></output></operation></binding><service name="MyclassService"><port name="MyclassPort" binding="tns:MyclassBinding"><soap:address location="http://Myclass/path/"/></port></service><message name="IdIn"><part name="id" type="xsd:string"/></message><message name="IdOut"><part name="return" type="xsd:struct"/></message></definitions>
```

Annotations vary on each generator.
I also tried nusoap but I was disappointed because of it's pure class method discovery. I must add that I'm testing usage of service with soapui (that's why I don't want php's SoapClient or equivalent examples).
Last I also must say that I tried solutions of adding authentication method inside my class and this worked ***BUT*** this didn't prevent unauthenticated user from accessing ws.

A little extra information. As of my research every answer I was found was about SOAPClient  for example the $client->__addheader() function etc. Please tell me if I' m wrong or if this can't be done with PHP because I ll have to find someone else to do this for me with another programming language like Java etc.

Thanks in advance

Dimitris

Comment: a WSDL is supposed to be public.. why are you trying to prevent it being public?

Comment: No I'm not it is exposed as it must be exposed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your clients send the authentication information in basically 3 places: SOAP Body, SOAP Headers, HTTP Headers. Of the three I think the proper one is SOAP Headers so I'll go with that for this example. (Note I'm using some custom auth header format, but I suggest you research about the WS-Security protocol.)

```
class Myclass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       /*some db stuff with doctrine*/
    }

    public function Auth($auth)
    {
       if (! $this->validateUser($auth->Username, $auth->Password)) {
           throw new SoapFault('Client.Authentication', 'Invalid username or password');
       }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $id
     * @return object
     */
    public function Id($id)
    {
        /*...*/
    }

    private function validateUser($user, $password)
    {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

---

Now for the client: I think you in your server role don't have to worry about which particular clients will be consuming your service, simply because you can't consider them all. That's why there are standards, to abstract from particular implementations. So, as long as you follow the standard, you can trust *any* client will comply. And luckily, SOAP headers are part of the standard.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <Auth>
            <Username>foo</Username>
            <Password>bar</Password>
        </Auth>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <Id>4</Id>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

That is the XML you are expecting to receive, regardless of the client.

---

Finally, the WSDL. From what I've read, neither Zend Autodiscover nor piotrooo's library support headers definition. Apparently Yii's CWebService does (with proper method annotations).

In the worst case scenario, you can write the WSDL yourself, or adapt it from the one generated with your library of choice.

Links:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebService
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-tip-headers/

---

UPDATE:

```
class Auth
{
    /**
     * @soap
     * @var string
     */
    public $Username;

    /**
     * @soap
     * @var string
     */
    public $Password;
}
```

---

```
class MyClass
{
    private $authenticated = false;    

    public function Auth($auth)
    {
        if ($this->validateUser($auth->Username, $auth->Password)) {
            $this->authenticated = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @soap
     * @header Auth $auth
     * @param string $id
     * @return object
     */
    public function Id($id)
    {
        if (! $this->authenticated) {
            throw new SoapFault('Client.Authentication', 'Invalid username or password');
        }

        //return $id;
    }

    private function validateUser($user, $password)
    {
        return $user == 'foo';
    }

}
```

---

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii/framework/yii.php';
$URL = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
    $gen = new CWsdlGenerator();
    $wsdl = $gen->generateWsdl(MyClass::class, $URL);
    header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    echo $wsdl;
}
else {
    $server = new SoapServer($URL . '?wsdl');
    $server->setClass(MyClass::class);
    echo $server->handle();
}
```

---

This is indeed working as expected with the sample XML I provided before.
(You just need to change `<Id>4</Id>` for `<Id><id>4</id></Id>`).

Comment: thanks for your time to answer. First of all I must ask, if i put auth function neither zend nor piotrooo's lib parse it as a soap header so the generated wsdl does not include the proper header, have you been able to achieva that and how? As for creating wdsl by myself is my very last solution and I'm trying to avoid it. For example I'm thinking of crating the soap header manually and concatenate it with the autogenerated. Before accepting your answer I ll try it again (I have tried it some time ago with out success) and report back here. Thanks again.

Comment: Zend doesn't seem to support soap headers, piotrooo apparently does, or at least has a `generateHeaderIfNeeded` method. I will look into that. Also, have you tried the Yii I linked? If none of this options work, I guess you just have to add a line to the wsdl.

Comment: WSDL aside, have you tried the class? For example, posting the sample xml from Soap UI to test?

Comment: When I was trying piotrooo's I didn't found this method and as far as I m concerned there is an open issue on piotrooo's about auth header on which I ve also asked the same. I haven't tried neither yii nor aside I ll give them a try and report as soon as I can

Comment: I saw that method in github, but I didn't get it installing with composer. I'm looking at yii now....

Comment: when we are using a generator library either zend or piotrooo we are using a class with the so called exposed soap methods like in
    $autodiscover->setClass('Ap');
How am I supposed to use the new Auth class, I 've tried the one class to extend the other without any luck

Comment: No, no extends. They are different classes. But use Yii as I showed you, the other ones don't support headers

Comment: Well I did the following:
1)installed yii via composer
2)created Auth class on a separate file (Auth.php) which I included
3)added Auth & validateUser methods and private $authenticated variable to Myclass
4)in my Id method on Myclass Ii added the if (!$this->authenticated) check and finally
5)I added the code above but the wsdl generated was very poor and without any exposed methods or proper header. I cannot post code and wsdl here because of characters limit

Comment: OMG !Alejanrdo I forgot to enter @soap to Id method annotation It worked!!!! Thank you so so much!!! cheers!!!!

Comment: that's 2 ids. `<Id ...><id ...>...</id></Id>`. Anyway, glad it worked! ;)

Comment: yes yes after checking back again my -deleted- comment I realized what you meant about double ids but thats ok thanks again